# How to annotate/aggregate string fields in Django

Tags: python, sql, django

I've got a complex dataset that, if sourced via raw SQL would involve a lot of joins and do odd things like use aggregator functions on string fields:

```
SELECT
    "trainer_trainer"."user_id",
    "trainer_trainer"."email",
    "trainer_trainer"."background",
    "trainer_trainer"."history",
    "trainer_trainer"."manualrating",
    COUNT("trainer_helperqueue"."id") AS "available",
    MAX("account_account"."photo") AS "photo",
    COUNT("trainer_trainersession"."id") AS "busy",
    MAX("account_account"."name") AS "name"
FROM
    "trainer_trainer"
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    "auth_user" ON ("trainer_trainer"."user_id" = "auth_user"."id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    "trainer_helperqueue" ON ("auth_user"."id" = "trainer_helperqueue"."user_id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    "account_account" ON ("auth_user"."id" = "account_account"."user_id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    "trainer_trainersession" ON ("auth_user"."id" = "trainer_trainersession"."helper_id")
GROUP BY
    "trainer_trainer"."user_id",
    "trainer_trainer"."email",
    "trainer_trainer"."background",
    "trainer_trainer"."history",
    "trainer_trainer"."manualrating",
    "trainer_trainer"."user_id",
    "trainer_trainer"."email",
    "trainer_trainer"."background",
    "trainer_trainer"."history",
    "trainer_trainer"."manualrating"
```

This query actually works quite nicely, but Django blows up internally when it tries to process the results:

```
Trainer.objects.annotate(
    photo=Max("user__account__photo"),
    name=Max("user__account__name"),
    available=Count("user__assistance_providing"),
    busy=Count("user__helping")
)

ValueError: invalid literal for float(): path/to/photo.jpg
```

Here's the tail end of the traceback:

```
PROJECTROOT/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.pyc in results_iter(self)
    705                         for (alias, aggregate), value
    706                         in zip(self.query.aggregate_select.items(), row[aggregate_start:aggregate_end])
    --> 707                     ]) + tuple(row[aggregate_end:])
    708 
    709                 yield row

PROJECTROOT/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.pyc in resolve_aggregate(self, value, aggregate, connection)
    320         else:
    321             # Return value depends on the type of the field being processed.

--> 322             return self.convert_values(value, aggregate.field, connection)
    323 
    324     def get_aggregation(self, using):

PROJECTROOT/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.pyc in convert_values(self, value, field, connection)
    298         it can be overridden by Query classes for specific backends.
    299         """
--> 300         return connection.ops.convert_values(value, field)
    301 
    302     def resolve_aggregate(self, value, aggregate, connection):

PROJECTROOT/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.pyc in convert_values(self, value, field)
    742         # No field, or the field isn't known to be a decimal or integer

    743         # Default to a float

--> 744         return float(value)
    745 
    746     def check_aggregate_support(self, aggregate_func):
```

ValueError: invalid literal for float(): photos/4/8/7/20120124111455-487767.jpg

The kooky thing is, that SQL query right there?  It's pulled directly from `db.connection.queries`.  Django ran it, it worked at the database level, and then Django flipped out handling the results.

Am I supposed to just not use `.annotate()` with non-numerical functions?  Is there a better/smarter way?

Comment: Is it intentional to have photo & name be the same value? Can you do pdb.pm() and see where float() is being called?

Comment: Heh, nope.  That was a copy/paste error, but the error is the same once I fix that.  Can you explain how to "do a pdb.pm()"?

Comment: `import pdb; pdb.pm()`. It'll give you an interactive debugger. 'u' and 'd' to go up/down the traceback frames; 'l' to show the surrounding code. Presumably float is getting called somewhere in django.db, but it's not the obvious place (django.db.models.aggregates). PDB docs: http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands

Comment: Ah I see.  It looks like ipython was giving me pretty much the same info, so I've attached it to the question here.

Comment: Well, I think the issue is just that django's ORM expects aggregates to always be numerical. I don't think you're going to be able to do anything about it; it looks like that assumption is pervasive in all the relevant code.